# The program downloaded from the education ev3 programming software has a error "VM program validation"

Tags: ev3-g

I cannot run the program from the ev3 software.It only shows "VM program validiation" How do I stop this from happening?

Comment: Do you get this for all Programs you try to run, or just this one?

Comment: All the old programs work except for this one.

Answer (score 1):

How did you download the program to the EV3? According to [this post on the Mindstorms forum](https://community.lego.com/t5/MINDSTORMS/VM-Program-Validation/m-p/8354382/highlight/true#M25461) this can occur if there was a problem sending the program, usually via poor quality Bluetooth adaptors.

You can confirm this if the downloaded program is only a few bytes in size on the Brick.

If this is the case, try downloading the program via a USB cable.

Comment: I used the usb  cable

Comment: Hmm, I assume you've tried deleting it from the EV3 and re-loading it?

Comment: I just learnt that the error occured because of another program had a similar name.